# Debezium connector for MySQL not picking up changes in database

Tags: apache-kafka, mariadb, debezium

I am using debezium connector for mysql, my database is MariaDB though

I load the config file for Debezium using `curl`

```
sudo curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{
  "name": "MARIA",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": "localhost",
    "database.port": "3306",
    "database.user": "user1",
    "database.password": "pass1",
    "database.server.id": "184054",
    "database.server.name": "test1",
    "database.include.list": "testDB",
    "schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
    "schema.history.internal.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.testDB",
    "include.schema.changes": "true",
    "topic.prefix": "debezium_mariadb_"
  }

}' http://localhost:8083/connectors
```

my problem that I notice right away is that the topic that get's generated does not have the prefix, it looks like `schema-changes.testTB`

I have confirmed that i am able to use the producer and consumer test scripts, so the problem is that changes on the MariaDB does not trigger whatever is supposed to get triggered

For comparisson I tested things out using the PostgreSQL connector

```
sudo curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{
  "name": "your-connector-name",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
    "database.hostname": "localhost",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "database.user": "user`",
    "database.password": "pass1",
    "database.dbname": "testDB",
    "database.server.name": "test1",
    "schema.include": "public",
    "table.include": "public.test",
    "publication.name": "debezium_publication",
    "topic.prefix": "debezium_postgres_"
  }

}' http://localhost:8083/connectors
```

And everything worked fine, I was getting JSON updates on changes.

The topic looks like `debezium_postgres_.public.test`

Is there something I have overlooked when it comes to the MySQL stuff? How can I troubleshoot why the connector is not picking up schema changes?

Comment: Removing `postgresql` tag as it has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Take note of [cross database updates](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replication-filters/#replicate_do_db). I'm not sure how Debezium implements them however missing data in replication stream seems consistent. How are the updates being performed?